# Maven Auth error with Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, authentication, passwords, artifactory

I'm trying to install artifactory in my local computer to manage all my project jars.
I've set up artifactory so it has two users: admin and user, without allowing anonymous login.
Here's my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>central</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>{encrypted-pssw}</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshot</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>{encrypted-pssw}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <name>remote-repos</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
        <id>remote-repos</id>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>central</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>artifactory</id>
                <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>Artifactory default repo</name>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>central</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

"{encrypted-pssw}" is the passord obtained from encrypting (mvn -ep) the encrypted password from artifactory.
When I try to install ("mvn clean install") or deploy ("mvn deploy") every project it gives me this error:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to remote-repos (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

I've tryied the rsa authentication too without any success

EDIT: more informations:

If I try to login with the broswer in the repository it asks for username and password, if I put them (using the encrypted password from artifactory) it allowes me to view the repository.

If I use as the url: http://user:passw@localhost:8081 it works and maven can login, but I need to do a lot of dirty work copying my password all over the projects if I use this workaround (note: the password used in the url is the one I get from the encrypted-password field in Artifactory, not the double-encrypted one I get from the maven command)

Comment: The question below means does this user have permission to DEPLOY to the remote repository, not view. Those are two different permissions. Can you please verify and update?

Comment: Yes, the user has all the permissions: if I login with the ip method (user:pssw@ip:port) it can deploy

Comment: Can you show the error that you are seeing in the artifactory.log after you are receiving the 
'Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to remote-repos (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
'
error?

Comment: Nothing is shown in the artifactory.log but In the request.log It prints this line: "20161101133853|1|REQUEST|127.0.0.1|non_authenticated_user|HEAD|/remote-repos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|0"

Comment: As you  can see in the request.log, the request arrives in Artifactory with no user: 'non_authenticated_user'. Usually, you would see another line, just under this line, where maven is sending another request with the credentials.

Comment: Another thing, can you drop the <mirrors> section from your settings.xml file and give it a try?

Comment: I reinstalled everything and reinstalled it following the steps I "logged" in another question, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to the following reasons:

1. Can you check if this user has deploy permission on the remote repositories that are being aggregated under the "remote-repos" virtual repository? If not you should grant the user deploy permissions to the remote repositories that are needed for the builds resolution. If you are not sure you can try using an admin user and see if it worked.
2. Check if in your Artifactory UI --> Admin --> Security configuration --> "Hide existence of unauthorised resources" is this checkbox checked? If so you will need to define "preemptive authentication" on maven (should be defined in your settings.xml file. See in google on how to add it.
3. Last thing that comes to my mind, can you double check that the encrypted password was written correctly in the settings.xml file?

Hope this will assist you with finding the root cause of the issue and resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove all mirrors in your file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>central</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>{encrypted-pssw}</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshot</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>{encrypted-pssw}</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>central</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>artifactory</id>
                <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>Artifactory default repo</name>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>central</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also check which settings.xml. According to the maven website:

```
There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
```

I was trying to modify the first settings.xml file with no luck, adding my credentials to the second one worked. If you run your maven command with the `-e` flag it will also tell you the settings file that it is trying to use